# Error en la creacion de nuevos post en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy creando una aplicacion en rails en la cual un freelance tiene una asociacion has_one con un servicio. la app va corriendo bien hasta que se debe crear un nuevo servicio como freelance. al crear un new post me sale el error.

Hice una prueba dejando la asociacion de freelancer con has_many y funciona perfecto dejando current_freelancer.services.build. pero con has_one me saca el error antes mencionado.

> NoMethodError in ServicesController#new undefined method `services'
>   for # Did you mean? service service=

el controller para los servicios es el siguiente.

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_service, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @services = Service.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @service = current_freelance.services.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @service = current_freelance.services.build(service_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.save
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

El mismo error te está diciendo la respuesta: `Did you mean? service`.
Si estás usando una relación `has_one`, debe ponerse en singular `service`, pero si es con `has_many` toca usar plural `services`. Convención sobre configuración.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

> Hice una prueba dejando la asociación de freelancer con has_many y
>   funciona perfecto dejando current_freelancer.services.build. pero con
>   has_one me saca el error antes mencionado.

Aqui esta tu error cuando la relación es has_one `service` debe ir en singular deberias reemplazar `current_freelance.services.build` por `current_freelance.service.build`